# Replace Function - Preserve Slashes and Other Special Characters

Tags: ms-access, replace, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a Microsoft Access 2013 database that I created to track time. The database has a FINDREPLACE table that I use to store shortcuts for certain often-used time entry text.  The table contains two fields, myFind and myReplace.  For example, one value in myFind is "telconf" and the corresponding entry in myReplace is "telephone conference with".  There is a button on the time entry form that calls a sub that loops through my FINDREPLACE table and replaces all of the shortcut "myFind" text in the time description with the corresponding "myReplace" text.  It works well and saves me from having to repeatedly type out the same lengthy phrases or names I can never remember how to spell.

Here is the sub:

```
Private Sub myFindReplace(myTime As Integer)
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rs, rs2 As DAO.Recordset
    Dim myMsg, mySQL, myTimeString As String

    If Me.Dirty Then
        myMsg = MsgBox("You must save your record before running FindReplace", vbOKOnly)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    mySQL = "SELECT * From TABLEFINDREPLACE"
    Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(mySQL, dbOpenSnapshot)

    myTimeString = DLookup("myDESCRIP", "TABLETIME", "ID = " & myTime)

    With rs
        Do Until .EOF
            myTimeString = Replace(myTimeString, !myFind, !myReplace)
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
    rs.Close

    myTimeString = UCase(Left(myTimeString, 1)) & Mid(myTimeString, 2)

    mySQL = "SELECT * FROM TABLETIME WHERE ID = " & myTime
    Set rs2 = dbs.OpenRecordset(mySQL, dbOpenDynaset)
    With rs2
        .Edit
        !myDESCRIP = myTimeString
        .Update
    End With
    rs2.Close
    dbs.Close
    Me.txtMyDESCRIP.Requery

End Sub
```

The sub that the button calls uses the VBA Replace function, and it works well in most instances. The problem arises when I want to includes slashes or other special characters in my replace text. For example, one of my "myFind" values is "emailtofrom", and the corresponding "myReplace" value is "e-mail correspondence to/from".  But, when I run the sub, the "emailtofrom" text is replaced with "e-mail correspondence tofrom", WITHOUT the slash.

I understand that the VBA Replace function will remove slashes and other special characters.  Is there anything that I can do preserve the slashes when the Replace function runs? Escaping the slashes somehow in my FINDREPLACE table (I'm the only one using this database so I can do that if necessary)? Using code other than VBA Replace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"I understand that the VBA Replace function will remove slashes"*

That is not what I see with VBA `Replace()`.   Here are examples from the Immediate window using forward and back slashes.

```vb
? Replace("foo emailtofrom bar", "emailtofrom", _
"e-mail correspondence to/from")
foo e-mail correspondence to/from bar

? Replace("foo emailtofrom bar", "emailtofrom", _
"e-mail correspondence to\from")
foo e-mail correspondence to\from bar
```

I think something else is going on, but I can't spot the issue in your code sample.  Set a break point, run your code, and then step through it one line at a time with the <kbd>F8</kbd> key and examine the text values at each step.

Comment: It is definitely something in the way the Replace function is operating in the sub.  I tried your experiment in the immediate window and got your same results.  But, for testing I added the following code after "myTimeString = Replace(myTimeString, !myFind, !myReplace)":
        `myMsg = MsgBox(!myReplace, vbOKOnly)
        myMsg = MsgBox(myTimeString, vbOKOnly)`
The "!myReplace" message box returns a result with a slash, verifying that it is pulling the correct text from TABLEFINDREPLACE. But the "myTimeString" message box returns a result without the slash.

Comment: When stepping through the code, don't bother with `MsgBox`.  You can hover the mouse over a variable or field, and its value will be displayed as a tool-tip.  Or do something in the Immediate window like `? !myReplace` ... and the value will be returned in the Immediate window.

Comment: If you upload a copy of your db to a file sharing site, I will look to see if I can figure out what's going on.  I have only 32 bit Access.

Comment: Mea culpa. My "emailtofrom" shortcut was conflicting with another "emailto" shortcut that I'd set up in TABLEFINDREPLACE.  I've renamed my shortcut "emailtofrom" to "emailtf" and now it's not being overwritten by "emailto" when the sub loops through all of the records in TABLEFINDREPLACE. Thank you for going out of your way to help--your offer to review an uploaded db caused me create a copy of my db and empty all of the table data, which led to my ultimate realization of my oversight.